# Visual Studio Code and typescript: automatic import and case sensitivity

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm building a project with TypeScript and React.

Sometimes I get this error regarding some imports:

> Already included file name '/app/src/store/DarkMode/Reducer.ts'
> differs from file name '/app/src/store/DarkMode/reducer.ts' only in
> casing.

Now, the file is called "reducer.ts" so it's lowercase, but when VSCode automatically import it it makes it uppercase:

```
// this automatic import imports "Reducer" instead of "reducer":
import darkModeReducer, { initialState, toggleDarkMode } from './Reducer'

describe('dark mode reducer', () => {
   test('should return the initial state if no known action is provided', () => {
        expect(darkModeReducer(undefined, {} as PayloadAction)).toEqual(initialState)
   })
})
```

if I manually change it from uppercase to lowercase:

```
import darkModeReducer, { initialState, toggleDarkMode } from './reducer'
```

I am presented with the same error. What can I do to fix this?